# How to Create a Carousel of Cards that show multiple at a time

Tags: bootstrap-4, carousel, blazor

I have a Blazor application with Bootstrap 4.5.3 installed.  I am looking to create a Carousel however id like to be able to have multiple items showing (Say 1 3 or 5 depending on screen width) and when you click the right or left buttons it shows the next 1 3 or 5 items.  Bootstraps carousel examples are only showing single items active.  Im looking to get something to this affect.  Can someone point my in the right direction either with a bootstrap example or know of a blazor or js component that achieves this?  Or if this is possible using the Virtualize Component but instead of Vertical scroll it is a horizontal scroll?

[image]